# filter an ng-repeat using buttons with angular

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to filter an ng-repeat, using buttons (later I will use inputs) and when I click a filter button everything disappears, and when I click the button with no filters everything keeps hidden.

I copied part of my code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3g3L0ca8/

```
<div ng-app>
<a id="filter-by-date" class="btn btn-success wide-btn" href="#" ng-click="myFilter = {date: 1900-12-31}">Select by date</a>
        <a id="filter-by-date" class="btn btn-success wide-btn" href="#" ng-click="myFilter = null">All the events</a>
<div ng-controller="Test">
    <div class="events-right-bar scrollable-content" id='hideshow' value='hide/show'>
    <section ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy:'date' | filter:myFilter">
        <div class="panel panel-default single-event">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialogTestDialog{{$index}}">{{event.title}}</button>
                    <em class="pull-right">Created by user: {{event.username}}</em>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Description:<br>{{event.description}} <br>
                <em class="pull-right">{{event.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }} - {{event.hour | date:"H:mm"}}</em> <br>
                {{event.duration}} minutes <br>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>

   </div> 
</div>
```

In the fiddle when I press the filter by date everything disappears too, I think it could by by the date format, but I'm not sure.But in the fiddle when I click no filter button everything appears again, in my project the no filter button does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the no filter button changing the "myFilter:null" by "myFilter:''"
Now I only have to solve the date problem, and I keep thinking it is a format problem.

edit: as I expected it was a format error. Even when the date is displayed as dd-MM-yyy it seems that in the filter it must be written yyyy-MM-dd. So the date I was trying as 27-11-2015 was wrong, it works writing it as 2015-11-27

Now it works